# Order in which Views are searched in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In what way views are searched in route.config file. I want the order in which views are searched.
e.g.

```
~/Views//Home/Index
~/Views/Shared/Home/Index
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: `/Views/{Controller}/{Action}` followed by `/Views/Shared/{Action}` (`/Views/Shared/{Controller}/{Action}` will not be searched unless you configure the view engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, MVC view engine searches available view cshtml files in these locations in order from top to bottom:

`~/Views/ControllerName/ActionName.cshtml`

`~/Views/Shared/ActionName.cshtml`

`~/Views/Shared/LayoutName.cshtml` (for layout files)

Either changing or re-ordering view engine search method requires creating a new class like this one:

```
public class CustomViewSearch : RazorViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewSearch()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };

        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            // you can change view search order here
            // {0} = action name, {1} = controller name
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;

        FileExtensions = new[]
        {
            "cshtml"
        };
    }
}
```

Then, place your custom view search method on `Global.asax` inside `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // remove all existing view search methods if you want
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); 

    // add your custom view search method here
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewSearch()); 
}
```

Any suggestions welcome.