# How to change file name in Visual studio project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a project solution in visual studio. Its created with MVC .net

I want to move some of my code files such as index.cshtml and others out of the Views>Home folder and into only Views folder. Will this break my project?
Also I want to rename index.cshtml to a new name, throughout all instances in my solution. When I tried this it only did the one file and it broke the project. I tried a CTRL F to find all index.cshtml, but it said there are no instances (though I know there are)
I need to rename the files correctly, so that I can deploy my project to match a current setup.

How do I rename all instances of index.cshtml in visual studio ?
And will moving the files outside of the home folder break the project?

I tried this it only did the one file and it broke the project. I tried a CTRL F to find all index.cshtml, but it said there are no instances (though I know there are)

Answer (score -1):

If you just starting out I'd recommend not moving/renaming view files by hand. Eventually you'll have good understanding of how view discovery works and will be able to move files to places where they can be found at run-time (and even add more places yourself).

ASP.Net is convention-based approach to locate view files - short version is by default runtime looks for .cshtml files with this name format "/views/{controller name}/{action name}.cshtml", you can change view name by specifying different name when returning `View("MyOtherView")` from controller.

For detailed information on how view discovery works see  [Order in which Views are searched in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286913/order-in-which-views-are-searched-in-mvc), [how to change order of search viewLocation in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088226/how-to-change-order-of-search-viewlocation-in-asp-net-mvc), [Microsoft - Views in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: So I cannot move the files out of the Home folder and put directly under view?
Nor rename the .cshtml file..?

Comment: You probably should fix up your automated ChatGPT posting script...